# encoder jpeg not available

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-class-based-views

I am trying to create a new model named as xxxx . I am trying to upload a image. So i created a model like below

```
 class xxxx(models.Model):
   description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True,verbose_name='Description')
   attachment = models.ImageField(verbose_name='ScreenShot', upload_to='instance/logo',blank=True)
```

while running a server am getting the error like below 
**encoder jpeg not available**

For that i tried to install pil such a things but am getting the same error which i said above statement.

Comment: Do you use Virtualenv? And also what OS?

Comment: yes, i am using  virtualenv and OS is ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few days ago.

I installed Pillow after uninstalling PIL, then issue has gone.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though when you installed Pillow, you didn't have the correct libraries to compile in (lib)jpeg support.

Before using pip to install pillow try to install:

```
sudo aptitude install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev
```

(and if that does not work, try searching for libjpeg and install the -dev library for it, in case you are using a different version of libjpeg)

Comment: when i execute the command, It will be removed the following packages 
  libkrb5-dev{u} linux-headers-3.2.0-64{u} linux-headers-3.2.0-64-generic-pae{u}

Comment: Try to install apt-get install python-dev python-setuptools

Comment: and apt-get install libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev libpng12-dev

Comment: try to reinstall pillow...  your OS is UBUNTU?

Comment: I have tried the command already. am getting the error like The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfreetype6-dev : Depends: libfreetype6 (= 2.4.8-1ubuntu2) but 2.4.8-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
 libjpeg-dev : Depends: libjpeg8-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Try still add this apt-get install libfreetype6-dev